# What is being signed by the custom signer?

Tags: java, pdfbox, bouncycastle

I have the following code to sign, the problem I am having is that the data that will be signed is being send over the network and I need to process it on another function but im not sure what type of encoding or hash does it have?

```
CMSSignedDataGenerator signGenerator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
                X509Certificate userCert = (X509Certificate) this.certificateChain[0];
                ContentSigner mySigner = new CustomSigner(invoke,String.valueOf(userCert.getSerialNumber()),sad);
                signGenerator.addSignerInfoGenerator(
                        new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build())
                                .build(mySigner, userCert));
                signGenerator.addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(Arrays.asList(certificateChain)));
                CMSProcessableInputStream msg = new CMSProcessableInputStream(content);
                CMSSignedData signedData = signGenerator.generate(msg, false);
                return signedData.getEncoded();
```

What does bouncy castle send to sign and in what encoding is it? I recieve on the other side the following

```
MYGYMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkFMQ8XDTIxMDMyMzE3MTA0NVowLQYJKoZIhvcNAQk0MSAwHjANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFAKENBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAvBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxIgQgpJ/2Sz3j0sp6iqVKmyednqFjZ87SYEYhScT0sSKtHPU=
```

Comment: It's base64. It decodes to some binary data with embedded ASCII digits.

Comment: but do you happen do know if its the hash of the data being signed or?

Comment: That blob is definitely not a CMS SignedData 'detached' signature, which is what Bouncy CMSSignedDataGenerator.generate(,false) returns. It looks like the re-built (with tag 0x31 instead of 0xa0) SignedAttrs from SignerInfo that is used internally in the signing and thus also verification processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jim Garrison and dave_thompson_085 already said in comments that's a base64 encoded signed attributes DER structure with content type, signing time, message digest, and algorithm protection properties. Here an [ASN.1 dump](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MYGYMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkFMQ8XDTIxMDMyMzE3MTA0NVowLQYJKoZIhvcNAQk0MSAwHjANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFAKENBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAvBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxIgQgpJ_2Sz3j0sp6iqVKmyednqFjZ87SYEYhScT0sSKtHPU) of it:

```asn1
SET (4 elem)
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.9.3 contentType (PKCS #9)
    SET (1 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1 data (PKCS #7)
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.9.5 signingTime (PKCS #9)
    SET (1 elem)
      UTCTime 2021-03-23 17:10:45 UTC
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.9.52 cmsAlgorithmProtection (RFC 6211)
    SET (1 elem)
      SEQUENCE (2 elem)
        SEQUENCE (2 elem)
          OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha-256 (NIST Algorithm)
          NULL
        [1] (2 elem)
          OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 sha256WithRSAEncryption (PKCS #1)
          NULL
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.9.4 messageDigest (PKCS #9)
    SET (1 elem)
      OCTET STRING (32 byte) A49FF64B3DE3D2CA7A8AA54A9B279D9EA16367CED260462149C4F4B122AD1CF5
```

According to the algorithm protection attribute BouncyCastle expects that you return a SHA256withRSA signature value signing this structure.

In particular, as you wonder *what type of encoding or hash does it have*, the hash of this structure still will have to be calculated as part of your signing service.

Comment: Thank you,
Im trying to read the OCTET STRING, but im stuck as how to parse it
```
private void localTesting(byte[] signatures) throws IOException {
        ASN1InputStream input = new ASN1InputStream(signatures);
        ASN1Primitive p;
        while ((p = input.readObject()) != null) {
            if (p instanceof ASN1Set) {
                ASN1Sequence asn1 = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(signatures);
                System.out.println(ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(p));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"but im stuck as how to parse it"* - what exactly do you want to parse it for? For signature creation you merely have to sign this byte array and return the signature bytes. So do you want to validate the structure you got? Or retrieve some specific information from it?

Comment: I need to extract the message diggest, as I need to check it against a hash im calculating in other function. From my understanding the message diggest part is the OCTET STRING

Comment: Yes, you see it in the example above as value of the `messageDigest` attribute.

Comment: So it would be the 32bytes correct("A49FF64B3DE3D2CA7A8AA54A9B279D9EA16367CED260462149C4F4B122AD1CF5") ? And do you know if thats already the hash(I know the name message digest is hash) but maybe it has not been processed

Comment: That is the hash value of the signed document bytes.

Comment: Thank you, just to double check the messageDigest attribute is the hash sha-256 of the document I have send to sign

Comment: *"just to double check the messageDigest attribute is the hash sha-256 of the document I have send to sign"* - Well, it's the SHA256 hash of the `content` contents in the code of your question. If `content` contains the document, then yes. But you have tagged your question [tag:pdfbox]; this might mean that you actually create integrated PDF signatures. If that is the case, the PDF you sent is first prepared for signing and then this prepared version (except a placeholder) is hashed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I made another question so that im not scope creeping and I can explain in a better way my question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67712321/message-diggest-in-a-base64-encoded-signed-attributes-der-structure